# Audit fields of a class using a class level annotation (aspectj)

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm writing a simple auditing framework with aspectj, which allows me to audit the fields of a class which are annotated with an @Audit annotation.
As value the @Audit annotation expects an array of field names to be watched

Example Usage:

```java
@Audit({"name","phoneNumber"})
class User {

    private String name;

    private String phoneNumber;

    public getName(){
        return name;
    };

    public setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

How does the Aspect look that watches the assignment of fields that are annotated like in the above example?

Here the stub of my first try:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Audit {
    String[] value()
}

@Aspect
class AuditAspect {

    @Pointcut("????")
    public void markedFieldWasModified(){}

    @AfterReturning("markedFieldWasModified()")
    public void addFieldToModifiedFields(JoinPoint jp, AuditableEO eo){
        eo.addModifiedField(jp.getSignature().getName());
    }

    // inter Type declarations
    public interface IAuditableEO {
        public Iterator<String> modifiedFields();

        public boolean modified();

        public boolean addModifiedField(String field);

    };

}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, the pointcut must be defined on setters (all "set*" method) of classes annotated with `@Audit`. 

You would then need to check if the method name matches with a field in `@Audit` params, and then process the new value. Maybe there's a way to add an observer on fields that I don't know though.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/quick5.pdf

you should be able to do `set(* *.*) && @target(Audit)`

you then have to check the joinpoint if an auditable field is being modified.

Answer (score 0):

How about not over-engineering the whole thing and directly annotating fields instead of classes? You can also skip the IAuditableEO interface IMO, I cannot see why it would be useful. Here is a simple example similar to yours, just with the aspect in code-style syntax (I prefer it to annotation-style syntax for clarity, but you can easily convert it by yourself):

**Audit annotation for fields (not classes):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Audit {}
```

**User class with a sample main method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class User {
    private int id;
    @Audit private String name;
    @Audit private String phoneNumber;

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String getPhoneNumber() { return phoneNumber; }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(11);
        user.setName("John Doe");
        user.setPhoneNumber("+49-1111-23456789");
        System.out.println("User(" + user.getId() + ", " + user.getName() + ", " + user.getPhoneNumber() + ")");
    }
}
```

**Audit aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.Audit;

public aspect AuditAspect {
    pointcut fieldModification() : set(@Audit * *);

    after() : fieldModification() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart);
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
set(String de.scrum_master.app.User.name)
set(String de.scrum_master.app.User.phoneNumber)
User(11, John Doe, +49-1111-23456789)
```

As you can see, only the annotated fields are caught, not the ID field. This permits for fine-granular auditing on a per-field basis. Furthermore in the advide you have everything you need if you want to record anything in and audit database: field type and name, class name and so forth.